# Measuring distance between point to polyline using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, distance, proximity

There are two lines

- A : polyline
- B : Axis

I created points along the line B with same interval using 'generated points along lines' tool of ArcMap.

I would like to measure the distance between these points and line A.

But If I use 'Near' tool, I could not get the perpendicular distance between line A and B.

How I can measure the ortho-distance between line A and points?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: No such thing as perpendicular between 2 lines unless they are parallel.